# After integrating react-paypal-express-checkout into the react js app, two buttons are shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

**Why PayPal button shows 2?**
How do I remove one? I tried but could not remove it.
[paypal button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28mm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-paypal-express-checkout is not an official package and itself uses a deprecated integration, so the best solution is to instead use the current official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js).

See the [storybook examples there](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default).